# Data types usage in java

Tags: java, variables, types, primitive-types

I am not new in java but when I write program I always use `int` Type of my variables. I want to know when I need to use `int` data, when `byte`, when `long` and so on... Can U explain me this with examples please.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You should use `byte` when you use APIs and structures like arrays which use bytes.  You should use `long` for values which don't fit into an `int`.

Comment: Are you sure you won't need `String`, `boolean`, `double`, `float` or arrays?

Comment: Is there a stack overflow question that is similar to what this is asking?  Quick search didn't reveal any. Perhaps the question should be edited before down voting due to grammar / apparent simplicity.

Comment: @Atreys If there isn't a pre-existing question on SO addressing this issue, it's because the question is tutorial in nature, whereas SO is meant to address specific programming problems, as outlined in the [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help). People who are "not new" to Java should have an understanding of primitive types that extends beyond the purely rudimentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking when to use float, double and long etc. This [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) can help you to understand.

For example, int is 32 bit but long is 64 bit. If you need to set a value over 32 bit you should use long to store data.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on how you wanna use them and what considerations would you have (size, data type,..etc). I would recommend going throw [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The types used should be the product of a deep thought about various of things, including (but not limited to) int over long (32bit vs 64bit), char over byte (user friendliness vs performance) , complex data structures over simple ones (Performance), backwards compatibility (JRE version), platforms the program's gonna run on (Windows? Unix? Mac OS?), readability of the code (Sometimes writing "`byte x = 0xFF; char ch = (char)x;` is worse than `char ch = 'a'` and the list goes on... of course some of the stuff I mentioned fit into more than one category.
This usually comes with experience. The more you code, the more platforms you want to support, the faster you want your program to respond etc...
You should always have a plan regarding your program:

1. What platforms will I support?
2. Is the task more important than performance?
3. ...
4. ...

I'm not saying you should carefully consider every type you choose, I'm saying you should always make the effort to tick all the V's and be satisfied about it, accomplishing everything you wanted.